# .xml sharepoint form which queries company sql server db

Tags: sql, xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can I embed SQL queries into an xml doc for the purpose of autofilling a web form with database information?

For Example, I want a line for user input:
Customer_ID:[___________________]

And I want it to retrieve stuff like:
Name: Nic Cage
Address: 123 Cage Street
City: Cage
State: CA

Sorry for being so damn vague, but I am quite lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML doesn't have live content like queries (unless you count XQuery to pull populate data from another XML document, which won't apply here). If you're on SharePoint (depending on version, since you didn't specify), you should be using things like Data Sources (set up through SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio or connection libraries) or forms in InfoPath.

If you're on an earlier version of SharePoint (200x) you can write an ASP.net page that has a SQL query that pulls its connection from a config file (though that's outdated)

Comment: Thank you, I will try these and post an update at assignment's conclusion... 2010 sharepoint, by the way

Comment: Hi @Graham. I incorrectly declined your addition of the SP2010 tag to the OP's question as the review screen doesn't show related answers (and attached comments). Your edit will still probably be approved, but it would help a little if your edit reason mentions that the OP added the info in a comment. I'll also try not to be so trigger-happy next time I see a "random" tag added.